# Range and Nullspace of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$$(Tf)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$
be a transformation from the vector space V of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which are continuous.  Describe the range and nullspace $T$.

To me it would make sense that clearly the kernel or nullspace would be all such functions at $f(0$, so
$$Ker(T)=\{f(x)\in V|x=0\}$$
As far as the range, this is where my confusion is coming in. If the space is of continuous functions, then wouldn't the image also be $V$?

Comment: The expression you give for $Ker(T)$ makes no sense; it is not even clear which variable is suppose to range, and over what. In any case you need a set of functions ($f\in V$) not function values ($f(x)\in\Bbb R$). And setting $x=0$ is meaningless, as $x$ is at best a name for the argument of $f$, not something one can compare against$~0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f\in ker(T)$ means $Tf(x)$ is the null function, hence $Tf(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt =0$ for any $x$ ...
Which continuous function $f$ has this property?

For range, what is the derivative of $Tf(x)$?

If (for any $f$) $Tf$ is differentiable and the derivative of $Tf$ is continuous, then this means that the range is at most $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ ...